# building dll to run python scripts in AutoCAD

Tags: c#, python, dll, ironpython

My goal is to run python scripts in Autocad. In order to do this I am using IronPython 2.7.9 to create a NET API. A difficulty encountered is that Autocad uses custom attributes for identifying commands, so my plan is to use this code which allows selection and loading of a Python script:

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;

using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;

using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;

using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;

using IronPython.Hosting;

using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

using System;



namespace PythonLoader

{

  public class CommandsAndFunctions

  {

    [CommandMethod("-PYLOAD")]

    public static void PythonLoadCmdLine()

    {

      PythonLoad(true);

    }



    [CommandMethod("PYLOAD")]

    public static void PythonLoadUI()

    {

      PythonLoad(false);

    }



    public static void PythonLoad(bool useCmdLine)

    {

      Document doc =

        Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;

      Editor ed = doc.Editor;



      short fd =

        (short)Application.GetSystemVariable("FILEDIA");



      // As the user to select a .py file



      PromptOpenFileOptions pfo =

          new PromptOpenFileOptions(

            "Select Python script to load"

          );

      pfo.Filter = "Python script (*.py)|*.py";

      pfo.PreferCommandLine =

        (useCmdLine || fd == 0);

      PromptFileNameResult pr =

        ed.GetFileNameForOpen(pfo);



      // And then try to load and execute it



      if (pr.Status == PromptStatus.OK)

        ExecutePythonScript(pr.StringResult);

    }



    [LispFunction("PYLOAD")]

    public ResultBuffer PythonLoadLISP(ResultBuffer rb)

    {

      const int RTSTR = 5005;



      Document doc =

        Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;

      Editor ed = doc.Editor;



      if (rb == null)

      {

        ed.WriteMessage("\nError: too few arguments\n");

      }

      else

      {

        // We're only really interested in the first argument



        Array args = rb.AsArray();

        TypedValue tv = (TypedValue)args.GetValue(0);



        // Which should be the filename of our script



        if (tv != null && tv.TypeCode == RTSTR)

        {

          // If we manage to execute it, let's return the

          // filename as the result of the function

          // (just as (arxload) does)



          bool success =

            ExecutePythonScript(Convert.ToString(tv.Value));

          return

            (success ?

              new ResultBuffer(

                new TypedValue(RTSTR, tv.Value)

              )

              : null);

        }

      }

      return null;

    }



    private static bool ExecutePythonScript(string file)

    {

      // If the file exists, let's load and execute it

      // (we could/should probably add some more robust

      // exception handling here)



      bool ret = System.IO.File.Exists(file);

      if (ret)

      {

        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();

        engine.ExecuteFile(file);

      }

      return ret;

    }

  }

}
```

[blog post with code](https://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2009/03/using-ironpython-with-autocad.html)

in the article, the author says I need to build a .dll of that script and add references to:

```
IronPython.dll
IronPythonmodules.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll
```

and "the standard references" to

```
acmgd.dll
acdbmgd.dll
```

I have downloaded a decompiler and have begun looking at the code for these .dll and there are of course many different pieces of code to look at. How do I figure out where to add the references for the PYLOAD script posted above so that I can begin executing python scripts in Autocad?

Much Thanks,

Comment: Note that the blog post you're referencing is from 2009, and the latest IronPython release is over a year old and is written against Python 2 standards. [Python 2 has been sunsetted](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) by the organization officially maintaining Python, so its standards will not be updated by that organization in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to compile the .NET code you posted into an assembly (call it "PythonLoader.dll", for example). Once you've created an assembly out of your PythonLoader code, you can reference it in the PYLOAD IronPython script by loading the assembly following one of the sets of instructions [here](https://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#id31). The examples the author give make use of `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath`, so I would probably start by doing that as well.

```
>>> import clr
>>> clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(path_to_PythonLoader.dll)
```

Note that you'll need to compile your .NET code to a version of .NET Core or .NET Framework that matches the framework version that your IronPython environment is targeting. (From [the IronPython 2.7.9 source](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/blob/4355f807916f9f0de1c25030fa06b56028850e5a/Src/IronPython/IronPython.csproj), it looks like it targets .NET Framework 4.5, .NET Core 2.0, and .NET Core 2.1.)